# RDD[(String,Iterable[GenericData.Record])] to Map[(String,RDD[GenericData.Record])]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD` which is of type `(String,Iterable[GenericData.Record])`. Now I want to save these iterables to paths based on the keys of this RDD. So for example if the RDD contained

```
("a",[1,2,3,4])
("b",[5,6,7,9])
```

I need to perist [1,2,3,4] under `result-path/a` and [5,6,7,8,9] under `result-path/b`. One way to do this - which compiles but fails on runtime - is the following:

```scala
implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSessionUtils.initSparkSession("Test")
implicit val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val re:RDD[(String,Iterable[GenericData.Record])] = ???
val hadoopConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

re.forearch {
   case (key,collection) =>
       val reRDD = sc.makeRDD(collection)
       reRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(s"$uri/$key",
        classOf[SpecificRecord],
        classOf[NullWritable],
        classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[SpecificRecord]],
        hadoopConf)

}
```

The problem here is that I cannot do this since SparkContext is not serializable.`re` is an `RDD` so invoking `foreach` on it must serialize the inner lambda and send over to the worker nodes. So I am trying to think of a way where I can convert the initial `re` into a `Map[(String,RDD[GenericData.Record])]` so that I can do the following:

```scala
implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSessionUtils.initSparkSession("Test")
implicit val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val re:Map[(String,RDD[GenericData.Record])] = ???
val hadoopConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

re.forearch {
   case (key,rddCollection) =>
       rddCollection.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(s"$uri/$key",
        classOf[SpecificRecord],
        classOf[NullWritable],
        classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[SpecificRecord]],
        hadoopConf)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys can be collected, and original RDD filtered for each key:

```
val re = rdd
  .keys
  .collect()
  .map(v => v -> rdd.filter(_._1 == v).values)
  .toMap
```